# c++ prevent changing reference through getter

Tags: c++, class, reference, getter

I am currently learning c++ and I am an experienced C# and Java developer.

I have a class `B` which contains a member of class `A`, and I want users of class `B` to be able to change values in class `A` but not be able to change the instance of class `A` itself.

Basically it want to prevent `b.getA() = anotherA;` being allowed.

Is this possible in c++ or is my design completely wrong here?

This is my small c++ program

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    void setName(string value)
    {
        name = value;
    }
private:
    string name = "default";
};

class B {
public:
    A &getA()
    {
        return anInstance;
    }
private:
    A anInstance;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    B b;
    cout << b.getA().getName() << std::endl; // outputs "default"

    b.getA().setName("not default");
    cout << b.getA().getName() << std::endl; // outputs "not default"

    A a;
    a.setName("another a instance");
    b.getA() = a; // I want to prevent this being possible 
    cout << b.getA().getName() << std::endl; // outputs "another a instance"
}
```

A C# example of what I am trying to do

```cs
class Program
{
    class A
    {
        private string name = "default";
        public string getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(string value)
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }

    class B
    {
        private A anInstance;
        public A getA()
        {
            return anInstance;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();
        Console.WriteLine(b.getA().getName()); // outputs "default"

        b.getA().setName("not default");
        Console.WriteLine(b.getA().getName()); // outputs "not default"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know `const`?

Comment: The "get" returns a reference to an instance.  The caller can't change the reference in the class unless you also provide a "set".  Don't do anything horrific like returning a pointer to a reference or a pointer to a pointer and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Robinson Why should changing the object not be possible?

Comment: btw I would recommend callers calling methods on B to modify B's instance of its A, rather than B returning an A.  It's just from experience letting A's roam free outside of their owning B's can lead to problems when you come to refactor or change things up.

Comment: You're returning a reference to A, not a reference or a pointer to B's reference or pointer to A.  Callers can change the A (because it's not const) but they can't tell B which A its using unless you provide a Set(&A) method.

Comment: my bad read too fast i deleted this stupid comment i made

Comment: @Robinson Yes, but a simple assignment (copy) like the one in the question (with or without overloaded operator) works. Replacing the object not, right, but copying the value.

Comment: An assignment or copy will change the caller's instance, not B's.  You're returning a reference to an object, not a reference to a reference to an object.

Comment: `string getName()` should be `const string& getName() const` (this is only ok when returning a member variable) and `setName(string value)` should be `setName(const string& value)` This causes less copies of the strings.

Comment: @Robinson Please try it before telling nonsense. As Neil Kirk now wrote too, const ist the solution, because else changing ist possible.

Comment: He specifically says in the question, "I want users of class B to be able to modify class A".  This isn't about const, it's about his assumption that assignment to the caller's reference will also change the reference in B, which it won't.  Don't be so rude and arrogant.

Comment: Sorry, but `An assignment or copy will change the caller's instance, not B's. You're returning a reference to an object, not a reference to a reference to an object.` Is just plain wrong, independent of how the question is understood.

Comment: Allowing callers to modify A but not to assign A from another instance is rather contradictory, as the latter is a special case of the former. You could disable `operator=` on your A class.

Comment: No it won't.  He's returning a reference to an A.  The caller can modify the A .  The caller won't be modifying which instance B thinks its A is.

Comment: @deviantfan yes I know const, but if I write my getter as `const A &getA()` then I cannot do `b.getA().setName("not default");` anymore. If I understand the discussion correctly and as pointed out by @Neil, what I am trying to do just does not make sense, if callers can modify `A`'s data by calling set methods, theres no reason they should not be able to copy the entire object.

Comment: As I said originally, if you want to enforce something like this, don't return a reference to A.  Put methods onto B that internally will change B's A.   It's good practice to keep internals hidden from callers.

Comment: @JfBeaulac In short, `b.getA() = anotherA;` does not do what you thought it did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote:

```
A a;
a.setName("another a instance");
b.getA() = a; // I want to prevent this being possible
```

I ask, why?

Why do you want to prevent that?

Your next line is:

```
cout << b.getA().getName() << std::endl; // outputs "another a instance"
```

But that is misleading, you **have not changed the instance of `A` inside `b`**, you've only changed `b.anInstance` to be *a copy* of `a`. In other words, you've changed the name to *say* `"another a instance"` but that doesn't mean it's true. It's no more true that it's another instance than if you called `b.getA().setName("another a instance")` (in fact, the result is identical to doing that!)

Try it:

```
A a;
a.setName("another a instance");
std::cout << &b.getA() << std::endl;
b.getA() = a;
std::cout << &b.getA() << std::endl;
```

You'll get the same address printed both times, because `b.getA() = a` does not *replace* `b.anInstance`, it just modifies it, just like calling `setName` does.

That's because in C++ `B::anInstance` is not just a reference to an `A`, it *is* an `A`, and so by assigning to it you don't change the reference to point to a different `A`, you change the `A` itself.

So, to go back to your original question, since the thing you're worried about *doesn't happen anyway* why do you need to prevent it?  If you already allow `b.anInstance` to be modified via the `setName()` function, why not just let it be modified by assignment as well?

If the answer to that question is that there are other properties of `A` which you don't want to be changed, and the assignment would change them, then instead of exposing the whole `A` object via `B::getA()` just add a new member function to `B` which sets the name. Doing this is better encapsulation than simply exposing the entire `A` object anyway. Too often Java and C# seem to encourage bad designs involving getters and setters for everything, which is pointless and encapsulates nothing; you might as well just make every member public and access them directly if there is a setter for everything.

If you want a `B` that contains an `A` that doesn't change except for its name, then don't expose the whole `A`, just provide a setter on the outer object:

```
class A {
public:
    string getName() const // N.B. Added 'const' here
    {
        return name;
    }
    void setName(string value)
    {
        name = value;
    }
private:
    string name = "default";
};

class B {
public:
    // Read-only access to the contained object:
    const A& getA() const
    {
        return anInstance;
    }

    // Update the name of the contained object:
    void setName(string value)
    {
        anInstance.name = value;
    }

private:
    A anInstance;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

When you allow general non-`const` access to a member (such as `A B::anInstance`), then this implies access to all the (`public`) members of that member (`const` and not). In particular, you provide access to the `operator=`, which allows the *contents* of the member to be changed. Of course, it's still the same `A` (with the same address), but its data have changed.

In your C# code you are actually never allowing/using non-`const` access to the `B::anInstance`, so your C++ is not really equivalent. Consider

```
 class B
 {
   A anInstance; // private by default
 public:
   A const& getA() const { return anInstance; } // const access only
   A      & getA()       { return anInstance; } // full access
   A       copyA() const { return anInstance; } // make a copy 
 };
```

The first `getA()` is accessible from `const B` and only allows `const` access to `anInstance`, i.e. only to `const` members of `A`. The second `getA()` is only accessible from non-`const` `B` and allows full (`public`) access to `anInstance`, including `A::operator=(A const&)` (if present, i.e. either declared or not `=delete` in the definition of `class A`).

Finally, `copyA()` provides no access whatsover to `B::anInstance`, but returns merely a copy to it. Typically (if `A` is non-trivial and/or large) this requires much more effort than merely returning a reference (like a pointer), but in terms of usage/effect, it is very similar to `getA() const` (it's different if some `const` member of `A` actually change the state of `A` or if you use the dreaded `const_cast<>` as in `const_cast<A&>(b.getA())=otherA`).

Answer (score 0):

explicitly disable value-copying!

```
private:
    A(const A&);
    A& operator=(const A&);
```

Comment: How does allowing the assignment operator to be called and exhibit unusual behaviour, help?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use const pointer instead of reference, but it can have a lot of side effects:

```
class A {
public:
string getName() const
{
    return name;
}
void setName(string value)
{
    name = value;
}
private:
    string name;
};

class B {
public:
A * const getA() const
{
    return anInstance;
}
 private:
     A* anInstance;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    B b;
    cout << b.getA()->getName() << std::endl; // outputs "default"

    b.getA()->setName("not default");
    cout << b.getA()->getName() << std::endl; // outputs "not default"

    A a;
    a.setName("another a instance");
    b.getA() = a; // I want to prevent this being possible 
    cout << b.getA()->getName() << std::endl; // outputs "another a instance"
}
```

As @Captain Price mentioned you can prohibit =operator of A class:

```
class A {
public:
string getName()
{
    return name;
}
void setName(string value)
{
    name = value;
}
private:
string name;
A& operator=(const A& other);
}; 

class B {
public:
A &getA()
{
    return anInstance;
}
private:
A anInstance;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
B b;
cout << b.getA().getName() << std::endl; // outputs "default"

b.getA().setName("not default");
cout << b.getA().getName() << std::endl; // outputs "not default"

A a;
a.setName("another a instance");
b.getA() = a; // I want to prevent this being possible 
cout << b.getA().getName() << std::endl; // outputs "another a instance"
}
```

Comment: Your example doesn't work because `anInstance` is never initialized.

Comment: @NeilKirk Its not working because its not compiling. You can init A* as you like. The question is not about this.

Comment: If you give an example which *looks* like it can be compiled and ran, it should either work successfully or you should explicitly state that it is not working.

Comment: @NeilKirk PS looks for a way to make this code NOT COMPILE. What are you talking about?

Comment: Captain Price's answer does not suggest prohibiting the assignment operator.

Comment: Returning a const pointer just means users have to do `*b.getA() = a` instead of `b.getA() = a`, so it only changes the syntax required to do it, rather than prevent it.

Comment: The second part, based on Captain Price's answer is the correct one, by deleting the assignment operator of A (or making it private, as he suggested) the assignment `b.getA() = a` is not allowed, just as it was asked for.